# Creating a DataFrame from a list of float values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list containing float values and I want to make a DataFrame out of it. But I am getting an error    TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

```
    '''python   
       newlist = []
       for i in path.toolpath:   
            newlist = [i.x, i.y,i.z, i.e, i.moveSpd]
            labels = ['x_coordinate' , 'y_coordinate', 'z_coordinate', 'e', 'speed'] 
       df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(newlist, columns = labels)
       print(df1)
    '''

A part of newlist is as follows.
    [-40.8629, 2.28, 44.3492, 1698.7625, 300]
    [-40.788, 2.28, 43.352, 1699.0625, 300]
    [-40.7131, 2.28, 42.3548, 1699.3625, 300]
    [-40.6382, 2.28, 41.3576, 1699.6625, 300]
    [-40.5633, 2.28, 40.3604, 1699.9625, 300]
```

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of what your dataframe should look like?

Comment: This isn't a pandas or dataframe question, it's pure python: "Why isn't the newlist variable  in my loop not getting updated?" You need to use the backtick character, not the single quote, to create code snippets. To your problem, the issue is that you assign to `newlist` the most recent `i` in each loop, overwriting whatever was in `newlist` previously. You could have found this by `print(f"i: {i}")` and `print(f"newlist: {newlist}")` inside your loop, and noticing that they both contain only the most recent `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your new_list variable is getting overwritten, you need to append the value.
Like this

```
newlist = []
for i in path.toolpath:   
    temp = [i.x, i.y,i.z, i.e, i.moveSpd]
    new_list.append(temp)
labels = ['x_coordinate' , 'y_coordinate', 'z_coordinate', 'e', 'speed'] 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(newlist, columns = labels)
print(df1)
```

Comment: its working but I am didn't understood why it was not working before as I was printing the newlist I was getting the output.